# Radio without the headset

Tags: fm-radio

**Is it possible to hear the radio without connecting the headset?**

I know the headset acts as an antenna.

However, it would be great if I can just put the phone on the coffee table and listen to the radio without being physically connected to it via a headset.

I am using Samsung Galaxy 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your radio station is an extremely obscure one, there is a high chance that it is available in [TuneIn Radio](https://market.android.com/details?id=tunein.player&hl=en). TuneIn uses your Internet connection (Wifi or 3G) instead of the FM wave so it does not require FM antennae.

Answer (score 3):

No. Your earphone is used as an antenna. But, If your phone has a built-in radio app, connect your earphone, open the app and turn loudspeaker.

Comment: Yes, this is the real answer as radio over wifi or 3g is not actual radio that's called internet radio and if you haven't figured out that your phone doesn't need headphones to access the internet you shouldn't be using a computer.